# Basic SQL COUNT queries

Tags: sql, count

I have a database below

```
f_name  l_name  post_code
John    Smith   3156
Sean    Jones   3156
Steve   Black   3114
michael Lever   3156
```

I want to create a count for each row that has the same post code. 
For example:

```
post_code    Count
3156         3 
3114         1
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which rdbms you are using?

Comment: Just google `sql count` on google, there are hundreds of examples

Answer (score 2):

Just do `group by`

```
select post_code, count(*) as Count
from table t
group by post_code;
```

Comment: The 1st and 2nd query looks same, When do they differ?

Comment: The `COUNT` result of the second query always is 1.

Comment: @schlonzo... Oh yes, `count(distinct <col>)` is redundant here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for:

```
select 
  post_code,
  count(distinct f_name, l_name)
from
  DATABASE
group by
  post_code
```

I also suggest you give a name to your variable count so it is easier to find it later.

Answer (score 1):

It simple query.

Use **GROUP BY  post_code**  Like.

```
select post_code, count(*) as totalcount
from table abc
group by post_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **GROUP BY** here.

**GROUP BY** - The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns.

**Query**:

```
select post_code, count(*) as totalcount from table table1 group by post_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume your table name is T1. Use the below query to get the expected output: (Please note you cannot use keyword "Table" as being used in the other answers, provided until I am posting this answer)

```
select post_code, count(*) as Count
from T1
group by post_code;
```

For some quick information/understanding on GROUP BY, you can refer to: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp